# Comparing GMRES to equivalent algorithms such as GCR

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If I understood correctly both GMRES and GCR minimise the residual norm on $x_0+K_k$. Hence, they produce the same approximations over the iterations. The difference comes from the fact that GMRES uses an orthonormal basis to build the approximations and GCR uses a $A^TA$ orthogonal basis. My question is why does it matter so much which basis we use and for which examples one method may be better than the other?

Comment: This is right.  The 1986 paper by Saad and Schultz [introducing GMRES](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme324/saad-schultz.pdf) outlines "several advantages over GCR and ORTHODIR."  Are you interested in a summary of these points?

Comment: I will read the article, thank you.